# How to initialize/format Azure Windows VM's Data Disks from ARM Template Deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy Azure Windows VMs using ARM Templates.

Although I've managed to add Data Disks to the Template, I then have to initialize them at the OS level from Disk Management.

Is there a way to initialize and format them automatically, while making the deployment?

How does the Azure Portal do it when you deploy from it?

Comment: Hi Can you give me the ARM template file for add Data Disks to the Virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [custom script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows), and this can all be done in Powershell, eg

```
PS C:\>Get-Disk | Where-Object OperationalStatus -eq 'Offline'| 
         Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru |
            New-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -DriveLetter F -FriendlyName 'New-Volume'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-volume?view=win10-ps

Comment: Thank you, David.
So, the only way to do it during deployment is to add the extension in the ARM Template and call the script?
Is that the way Azure does it as well?
Seems a bit non-optimized.