# ARM Template for VM Having Statically and Dynamically Defined Disks

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create an ARM template for a VM to deploy a custom application.
VM is based on this ARM template quickstart for a SQL Server VM:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-sql-vm-new-storage/

I need to create one disk first for my application, followed by the "copy" function to define the remaining disks.

This is how the quickstart originally defines the disks: (the createOption in the variables is "empty")

```
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "dataDisks",
              "count": "[add(parameters('sqlDataDisksCount'), parameters('sqlLogDisksCount'))]",
              "input": {
                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                "createOption": "[variables('dataDisks').createOption]",
                "caching": "[if(greaterOrEquals(copyIndex('dataDisks'), parameters('sqlDataDisksCount')) ,'None', variables('dataDisks').caching )]",
                "writeAcceleratorEnabled": "[variables('dataDisks').writeAcceleratorEnabled]",
                "diskSizeGB": "[variables('dataDisks').diskSizeGB]",
                "managedDisk": {
                  "storageAccountType": "[variables('dataDisks').storageAccountType]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
```

As I need an extra 512 GB disk for the application that I want to place at the beginning, I modified my template as follows:

```
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "dataDisks",
              "count": "[add(1, add(parameters('sqlDataDisksCount'), parameters('sqlLogDisksCount')))]",
              "input": {
                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                "createOption": "[variables('dataDisks').createOption]",
                "caching": "[if(greaterOrEquals(copyIndex('dataDisks'), add(1, parameters('sqlDataDisksCount'))) ,'None', variables('dataDisks').caching )]",
                "writeAcceleratorEnabled": "[variables('dataDisks').writeAcceleratorEnabled]",
                "diskSizeGB": "[if(equals(copyIndex('dataDisks'), 0), 512, variables('dataDisks').diskSizeGB)]",
                "managedDisk": {
                  "storageAccountType": "[variables('dataDisks').storageAccountType]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
```

When the VM is created my desired disk is unallocated, it does not appear as a usable disk.
I tried changing the createOption configuration to be:

```
"createOption": "[if(equals(copyIndex('dataDisks'), 0), 'attach', variables('dataDisks').createOption)]"
```

But that throws an error of

```
18:58:27 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 6:58:27 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'myVM' failed with 
18:58:27 - message '{
18:58:27 -   "error": {
18:58:27 -     "code": "InvalidParameter",
18:58:27 -     "message": "Required parameter 'dataDisk.managedDisk.id' is missing (null).",
18:58:27 -     "target": "dataDisk.managedDisk.id"
18:58:27 -   }
18:58:27 - }'
```

I also tried to define the other disk outside the copy loop but that did not work either.
Not sure how I should go about this. Help??

Comment: if use use attach, you need to give a resourceId for the disk (hence the error).  Do you just want to add one disk to the array of disks already passed in as a param?  (implicit disk) or do you want to use an existing disk (explicit disk)

Comment: I want to create a standalone disk that is visible as an individual drive, for me to install applications on. I want it to be the first disk in order for the drive letter to be consistent. I'm very new to ARM templates so I might be going about it in a wrong way or missing something very obvious.

Comment: I should initialize the disk. The ARM template will create the resource and "attach" it to the VM, where attach means link but it will still leave it unformatted and uninitialized.
Initializing it can be done like in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673709/how-to-initialize-format-azure-windows-vms-data-disks-from-arm-template-deploym

Comment: Got it - your template code looks fine for that scenario, and yeah, you just need to "format" the disk before using it.